The bulk download from AWS s3 is failing
This code was working fine until a few days ago. However, we noticed that it is failing exactly after downloading 40 files. I don't remember changing any configuration parameters in the recent past.
Tried isolating by validating these scenarios:

Different images
Different folders
Different users
Different S3 buckets
Different servers - staging and production - Issue is occuring in both
No memory (storage and RAM), file permission issues as presigned
urls are accessible and sufficient storage and memory is available
on the servers

What's puzzling is - why the download is failing exactly after the 40th file? The client (browser) is getting the error "Unable to download the zip file. Please retry on a high speed internet connection or contact support, if issue persists!". This is the response returned to the client from catch block.
Of course, this error can be fixed. But, it doesn't help the user to download beyond 40 files even if there are more.

Is it possible that the process moved to populating $ImagesZip array before the files are download?
If so, how come it is failing exactly after 40 files every time? There can be different sizes of files and some may take longer/ shorter as per their size.

I'm out of my wits here. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Here below the sanitized code:
public function downloadZip(Request $request) { 

    $reqdata = $request->all();
    $ordref = @$reqdata['ordref'];
    $usrnumber = @$reqdata['usrnumber'];

    if (!$ordref || !$usrnumber) {
    //check if parameters passed valid
        echo json_encode($data);
        exit();
    } 

    $this->db = DB::table("orders AS o");
    $details = $this->db->select("o.photos", "o.ref", "o.id", "o.folder_id", "o.price","o.is_download")
            ->where(....)
            ->first();

    if (!$details) {
        return redirect("/");
    }

    //check if json is valid
    $images = $this->processphotos($details->photos);

    // find photo ids from DB        
    ....
    ....
    $dbimages = $this->getimagesbyids($imageids);

    $imageNames = [];
    foreach ($dbimages as $item) {
        $thumbName = $item->imgurl;
        array_push($imageNames, array('image' => $thumbName, 'category' => $item->category, 'id' => $item->id));
    }


    if (!$imageNames) {
    //return No images found error.

    }

    $zipimages = [];
    $public_dir = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'downloads' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $zipimagesarray = array();
    $imagepatharray = explode("/", $imageNames[0]['image']);
    $imagename = end($imagepatharray);

    $ctr = 100;
    foreach ($imageNames as $row) {
        $imgtype = 'jpg';
        $prefix = $usrnumber.'_';
        $imagename = $prefix . $ctr . $imgtype;
        $signedurl = $this->getpresignedurl($row['image']);
        @ File::copy($signedurl, $public_dir . $imagename);

        array_push($zipimagesarray, array('path' => $public_dir, "image" => $imagename));
        $ctr++;
    }

    $imageZip = [];
    $certZip = [];
    foreach ($zipimagesarray as $imagePublic) {
        $path = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,$imagePublic['path']);

        $zipImage = $imagePublic['path'] . $imagePublic['image'];
        array_push($imageZip, $zipImage);
    }

    try {
        $zipName = $usrnumber . date('G:i:s') . ".zip";

        Zipper::make(public_path('downloadOrder/' . $zipName))->add($imageZip)->close();

        File::delete($imageZip);
        $file = "/download/" . $zipName;

        $data['result'] = array();
        $data['result'] = url('/') . $file ;
        $data['statusCode'] = 200;
        $data['hasError'] = false;
        $data['message'] = "Images retrieval is successful.";
        return response($data)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        $data['result'] = array();
        $data['statusCode'] = 400;
        $data['hasError'] = true;
        $data['message'] = "Unable to download the zip file. Please retry on a high speed internet connection or contact support, if issue persists!";
        Log::error("Api::downloadZip - orderId: " . $data['Message'] . " " . $ex->getMessage());
        return response($data)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
}

and
function getpresignedurl($key, $s3Client = null) {

$s3_env = [];
$Bucket = "xxxxx";

if (is_null($s3Client)) { 
   $s3_env = array('region' => config('aws.AWS_REGION'),
       'credentials' => ['key' => config('aws.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), 'secret' => config('aws.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')]);
   $s3Client = \App::make('aws')->createClient('s3', $s3_env);
}

//Creating a presigned URL
$cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
    'Bucket' => $Bucket,
    'Key' => $key
]);

$request = $s3Client->createPresignedRequest($cmd, '+30 minutes');
$signedurl = (string) $request->getUri();
return $signedurl;
}


Remove all silent operators @ from code. Also read actual error message from \Exception $ex and not your own random text (or just actually read your error logs)

Maybe you are hitting account requests limits?

@Justinas, Thanks for the response. There are over 100 users requesting simultaneously and all of them are able to download exactly the same number, but different files. I'll check the other suggestion about silent operator and actual error message from exception.

On further analysis, I figured that the signedurl is automatically changing the query parameters from "&" to "&" from 41st file in the File::copy and it is failing with "File Copy Exception: copy(https://bucket.xxx/img1.jpg?X-Amz-Content-Sha256=UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&.....): failed to open stream: operation failed

Well, This is not the exact solution for the issue reported.
I have addressed it by implementing entirely a new approach. Introduced a new method downloadFile and used AWS SDK GetObject command to download the files. Even saveAs parameter in GetObject did not come to the rescue. This solution getObject with SaveAs not working in sdk v3 helped.
function downloadFile($key, $destination, $s3Client = null) {
     $s3_env = [];
     $Bucket = "xxxxx";

     try {
        if (is_null($s3Client)) { 
            $s3_env = array('region' => config('aws.AWS_REGION'),
                'credentials' => ['key' => config('aws.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), 'secret' => config('aws.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')]);
            $s3Client = \App::make('aws')->createClient('s3', $s3_env);
        }

        //Creating a presigned URL
        $cmd = $s3Client->getCommand('GetObject', [
           'Bucket' => $Bucket,
           'Key' => $key,
           '@http' => ['sink' => $destination]
        ]);

        $result = $s3Client->execute($cmd);

        if ($result['@metadata']['statusCode'] === 200) {
            return true;
        } else {
            Log::error("Api::downloadFile - Failed to download to $destination " . $result['@metadata']['statusCode']);
            return false;
        }
    } catch (\Exception $ex) {
        Log::error("Api::downloadFile - exception: $ex->getMessage()");
        return false;
    }
}

And in the main method downloadZip, replaced these lines
    $signedurl = $this->getpresignedurl($row['image']);
    @ File::copy($signedurl, $public_dir . $imagename);

with
    $destination = $public_dir . $imagename;
    $result = $this->downloadFile($row['image'], $destination);

Also, to handle download failures, added an if condition
if (file_exists($public_dir . $imagename) {        
    array_push($zipimagesarray, array('path' => $public_dir, "image" => $imagename));
}

I'll wait for a few more days if someone can offer a solution on why automatic html encoding is happening after 40th file and then accept this as a solution.
